# Почему не срабатывает условие if is_tax для субкатегорий WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php if (is_tax('buildings', 'type-a')) { ?>
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/floorplan/level/floorplan_a_2-9.png">
 <?php } elseif (is_tax('buildings', 'type-b')) { ?>
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/floorplan/level/floorplan_b_2-9.png">
```

Работает только в категории **buildings/type-a** и **buildings/type-b**
в суб-категории buildings/type-a/**subcategory** не срабатывает
подскажите пожалуйста как решить ?

Comment: Использовать другую функцию. Например `get_category_parents()`

Comment: конкатенации нет, учи как кавычки двойные и одинарные делать. точки

Comment: @Bloom конкатенации чего? Аргументов функции?

Comment: <?php if (is_tax('buildings', 'type-a')) {
 echo '<img src='.bloginfo("template_url").'/assets/img/floorplan/level/floorplan_a_2-9.png>';
 } elseif (is_tax('buildings', 'type-b')) {
 echo '<img src='.bloginfo("template_url").'/assets/img/floorplan/level/floorplan_b_2-9.png>';
 ?>  попробуй так

Comment: получилось?....

Comment: @Bloom а что поменялось кроме лишнего ехо? Как ехо влияет на поведение функции?

Comment: @Bloom не пойму а echo как то повлияет ?